# Find $\cos \theta_3$ where $\theta_3$ is the angle line $P$ makes with positive $y$ axis given also $\theta _2,\theta_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given a point $P(x,y,z)$ in the octant of space where $x,y,z \gt 0$,the line
>   connecting point $P$ with the origin makes angles $ \theta _1$ with
>   the $x$ axis, $\theta_2$ with the $y$ axis and $\theta_3$with the $z$ axis.
>
> Given that $\cos \theta_1=R$ and $\cos \theta_2=S$, find $\cos
>  \theta_3 $.

This is what I've done (in the following three cases I've considered the unit vectors $\vec i,\vec j$,$\vec k$ where $\vec i =(1 \space \space \space 0 \space \space 0)$,$\vec j=(0 \space \space \space 1 \space \space \space 0)$ and $\vec k=(0 \space \space \space 0 \space \space \space 1)$$\space$).

Considering $\theta _1$ we have that $\cfrac{\vec{k}\cdot \vec P}{||\vec k||\space||\vec P||}=\cos \theta_1=R$  .

This simplifies to $\cfrac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=R$ $\tag 1$

Considering now $\theta_2$ we have that $\cfrac{\vec i \cdot \vec P}{||\vec i|| \space ||\vec P||}=\cos \theta_2=S$ $\implies S=\cfrac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ $\tag2$

Finally, $\cfrac{\vec j \cdot\vec P}{||\vec j || \space ||\vec P||}=\cos \theta_3$ $\implies \cos \theta_3=\cfrac{y}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ $\tag3$

Rearranging $(1)$ and$(2)$ it yields $\cfrac{R}{z}=\cfrac{S}{x}$ and $\cos \theta_3=\cfrac{R \cdot y}{z}=\cfrac {S\cdot y}{
x}$.

This is what I was able to get,but I don't know if this can be simplified any further so that I have $\cos \theta_3$ only in terms of $S$ and $R$...

Can I have some help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is an error in your formulas for $\cos\theta_i$, because $||\vec P||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Then you just need to observe that $\cos^2\theta_1+\cos^2\theta_2+\cos^2\theta_3=1$.

Comment: Didn't see that mistake .Thanks for the help.